# Client routes protection with localstorage

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, local-storage

I have a react/laravel app that currently uses a variable stored in the `localStorage` to do routes protection.

When a user is authenticated on the server side, front end saves a variable `logged-in` to `true` in `localStorage`. In react, on route enter, it checks if `logged-in` variable is set in `localStorage`. if not, redirects to login component.

The problem is that user can just modify their `locaoStorage` with javascript or in their js console to cheat the UI authorization.

So how should i go about preventing this? Or is there a better approach to protect routes in react? Thanks.

Comment: You cannot prevent the user modifying anything on the client, localStorage, sessionStorage, indexedDB. Its all accessible in devtools and the JavaScript console. You really should not be using such storage mechanisms for authentication data.

Comment: Client can be always corrupted - makes no sense to protect your client - server is the line of defense.

Comment: data is protected by the server. its just when users change the `localStorage` and go to a protected page, the page will just be a spinner spinning. Or if they delete the token in `localstorage`, they will be treated unauthenticated on the client even though they are on the server. The UI just seems a little broken when the `localstorage` is changed by users.

Comment: Can you alter the way react checks `logged-in`? Could it be replaced by a real method call to the server to see if a user really is authenticated? That being said, could the entry `logged-in` have some expiration mechanism?

Comment: @peter_the_oak hmm yea i guess i can make a method call to the server. but what would expiration mechanism used for? like a storing a timestamp in the localstorage?

Comment: I was thinking of a way to conditionally get the real value from the server and store and use it, as long as you are sure it is valid. That way you could save some time. Timestamp is one possibility, but it brings along its problems. I was rather thinking of a way to find out if a user has tampered with the values :-) That's what you would like handle, isn't it?

Comment: i see. but the problem is where can you store the value you get from the server?